# How does a Website with Facebook login work practically?

Tags: facebook, web

If I create an app for my wesite under the tab 'website with Facebook login' - how does this work for users accessing my site?

Do users HAVE to sign in with Facebook to view my site?

Or would they only be prompted to sign in if they were not signed in and they clicked my Like or Send buttons (the only button's we'll have)?

If a user doesn't click the like or send - will they be affected?

As much details about the user experience as possible wouldbe great. Cheers all!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook login is usually just a wrapper on top of your website that allows you to get Facebook user details if they use Facebook.  You will still need a system to track who is actually logged in to your site and they will still have to click the "Login with Facebook" button.

On the other hand, the Like and Share buttons are independent as they simply send your website data to Facebook and Facebook does not send anything back to you.

You do not need Facebook login functionality to put Like or Share features on your page.